# How to programmatically delete a specific plot in mayavi

Tags: python, mayavi

I made a bunch of plots using stuff like

```
plot_to_delete_later = mlab.points3d(...)
```

I want to remove this later on, but keep the other plots. I can do this in the GUI (see image), but can't seem to find the trick to doing it in code.

Any help much appreciated.

[image: gui_version]

Comment: It should be `plot_to_delete_later.remove()` but FYI mayavi is extremely bad at releasing memory so probably `remove()` will result in a memory leak.